# Run Command on Sendmail Receive mail

Tags: email, sendmail, postfix-mta

I'm working on functionality in which, when Email arrive in any of Virtual Email (Generating Dynamically) then it should call my php script OR command. So i can extract this mail and insert data into my database.

In postfix I know, you just need to put that command in configuration file.

```
    mailbox_command = php /file/path/to/phpScript.php
```

Do anyone has idea, how to achieve same things in SendMail?

If anything that I'm not aware kindly correct me.

Thanks !!

P.S. I know concept of .forward file in User's home folder, but in such structure where you may have lot's of virtual account it's not feasible to achieve this.

Comment: How do you want to get information about envelope recipients in the script?

Answer (score 2):

In sendmail, you can achieve this with `/etc/mail/virtusertable` and `/etc/mail/aliases`

```
#/etc/mail/virtusertable
user@example.com     virtualuser

#/etc/mail/aliases
#... Other aliases
virtualuser: |/file/path/to/phpScript.php
```

`/etc/mail/aliases` database contains list of virtual mailboxes that are expanded to other user(s), files, programs, or other aliases. More info [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/sendmail.html)

Comment: You'r almost right, you just missed to write proper command, virtualuser: "| php /file/path/to/phpScript.php" ... Then i reload configuration through sendmailconfigure command. Thanks ..